# how to push an array to embedded mongo collection?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

How can we push an array to the mongo collection?

consider I have an array

```
 ar = ['a','b','c'].
```

1. I used $push to update an existing document. But how to push when i am creating collection document for the first time?
2. From the above mentioned method data stores like 
   ex:

   ```
   data{
     '_id': some_id,
     'array': Array
           0 : 'a',
           1 : 'b',
           2 : 'c'
   }
   ```

But how to store like this?

```
data{
  '_id': some_id,
  'array': ['a','b','c']
}
```

If second is possible, which one can be extracted easily?

Comment: I think you will find they are the same thing. The above example looks like the output in a GUI like Compass or Robo3T. Look at the document in the [`mongo` shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) or something similar. `$push` only creates/appends to "arrays", and nothing else.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks man.